# Why can't I use GuzzleHttp in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Keep getting the following error:

Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to string

```
 $response = $client.post('url', [
                'body' => [
                   'blah' => 'blah'
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    // client id+client secret (base64)
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic sllalalalal='
                ]
            ]);
```

I'm not using a route object anywhere, is all hardcoded strings in the array.  The line the error happens is exactly where the semicolon is.

Comment: Will need more code or maybe a stack trace to see whats going on here, that code is not enough to go by, at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$client.post` to `$client->post`. Currently you are trying to concat `$client` and `post()`.

Comment: well, you can see from that I'm a c# type of guy. heh. Thanks, btw!

Answer (score 0):

### Guzzle 4

#### PHP 5.4.x+ required

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle" "~4.0"
```

---

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->post('url', [
                'body' => [
                   'blah' => 'blah'
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    // client id+client secret (base64)
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic sllalalalal='
                ]
            ]);
```